# Changing Searcher Icon when user start typing

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am trying to change the SearchBar search icon to back button like google maps when user starts typing.

I  used following code

```
[[[UISearchBar class] appearance] setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"icon_me"] forSearchBarIcon:UISearchBarIconSearch state:UIControlStateNormal];
```

But this will set Icon at the starting itself , not when we start typing 
and i have to write this line in viewDidLoad only.

Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement delegate method of `UISearchBar` to do so.

```
- (void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText;   // called when text changes (including clear)
- (BOOL)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text;
```

In the delegate method you need to do this

```
UITextField *textField = [searchBar valueForKey:@"_searchField"];
textField.textColor = [UIColor brownColor]; //you can set text color
textField.leftViewMode = UITextFieldViewModeWhileEditing; //set leftViewMode or you can also set rightViewMode also

UIImageView *imgview = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 20, 30)];
imgview.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"searchIcon.png"]; //you need to set search icon for textfield's left/right view as you want

textField.leftView = imgview;
//textField.rightView = imgview; //you can set at right side also
```

Comment: Thanks for replying .Already i have tried this . But it didn't work for me