# How to show the custom Search Bar?

Tags: ios, iphone, uinavigationcontroller, uisearchbar, uisearchdisplaycontroller

Hi I am working with the UISearchDisplay controller.working fine But it is showing like Apple's Default one.But I need like below image[image]

But in app it is showing like below

[image]

I am using working with the Storyboard.

Comment: you need to customise as per your need.

Comment: that's what i am asking is there any way to display the searchBar in navigationBar like above

Comment: Here is answer of your question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36542549/customize-search-bar/36543336#36543336 or you can also refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36597324/changing-searcher-icon-when-user-start-typing/36598350#36598350

Comment: So we need to customize other componants like searchBar But what about display Controller is that disaplay based on searching string.I am using NSPredicate for disaplying strings.

Comment: Yes, we definitely can customise search bar.

Comment: Thankyou very much

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't customise it. If you want it to look different, roll your own from a UITextField and a UIButton.